# How to change "defaultOptions" lang in highCharts dynamically

Tags: javascript, internationalization, highcharts

I have highcharts that I am trying to internationalize. I Currently they are set default

```
defaultOptions ={...    
lang: {
    loading: 'Loading...',
    months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
            'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
...}
```

I have a properties file, and a method that writes what is in my properties.

`methodtowrite['highcharts.months.array']();`

but when i do something like

```
lang:{
     loading: methodtowrite['highcharts.months.loading']();
     months: methodtowrite['highcharts.months.array']();
}
```

the chart doesnt show up. I have a feeling i'm inserting the `methodtowrite` the wrong way. `methodtowrite` works fine and is correctly coded. i am using it in other JS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the semi-colons to commas. e.g

```
lang:{
 loading: methodtowrite['highcharts.months.loading'](),
 months: methodtowrite['highcharts.months.array']()
}
```

Check that methodtowrite'highcharts.months.loading' returns a string and methodtowrite'highcharts.months.array' returns an array.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZurX/

Comment: thanks. silly mistake, but I guess if anyone is making the same one they'll find it here.